# sm.current does not switch the screen

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am new to Kivy / MD platform and trying to build a simple login screen, but unfortunately in the authentication part, the screen manager does not switch to the selection screen. Can someone please help me here ?

My test.kv file looks like this

```
windowManager:
    Welcome:
    SelectionOption:


<Welcome>:
    id: welcome
    name: 'welcome'
    manager: 'sm'
    emailInput: emailInput
    passwordInput: passwordInput
    MDScreen :
        md_bg_color : [102/255,153/255,153/255,1]
        MDCard :
            size_hint : None, None
            size : 300, 450
            pos_hint : {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            padding : 20
            spacing : 30
            orientation : "vertical"

            MDLabel :
                text : 'Manager'
                font_style : 'Overline'
                font_size : 30
                halign : "center"
                size_hint_y : None
                height : self.texture_size[1]
                padding_y : 10

            MDTextFieldRound :
                id: emailInput
                hint_text : "Email address"
                icon_right : "account"
                size_hint_x : None
                width : 220
                font_size : 15
                pos_hint : {"center_x":.5}
                color_active : [0.2,0.2,0.1,1]
                TextInput:
                    multiline: False

            MDTextFieldRound :
                id: passwordInput
                hint_text : "password"
                icon_right : "eye-off"
                size_hint_x : None
                width : 220
                font_size : 15
                pos_hint : {"center_x":.5}
                color_active : [0.2,0.2,0.1,1]
                password : True
                TextInput:
                    multiline: False

            MDRoundFlatButton :
                text : 'Login'
                pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                font_size : 20
                text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_press:
                    root.validatelogin()

            MDRoundFlatButton :
                text: 'NEW USER'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':0.4}
                font_size: 20
                text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_press:
                    root.signup()

            Widget :
                size_hint_y : None
                height : 30

<SelectionOption>:
    info : info
    name : 'selection'
    MDLabel:
        id: info
        text : 'Selection Option'
        font_style : 'Overline'
    MDRoundFlatButton :
        text: 'Login'
        pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        font_size : 20
        text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
```

And the validate function looks something like the below

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (350, 580)

class Welcome(Screen):
    emailInput = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwordInput = ObjectProperty(None)

    def validatelogin(self):

        if self.emailInput.text == "123" and self.passwordInput.text == "123":
            sm.current = "selection"


class SelectionOption(Screen):
    pass


class windowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = windowManager()
sm.add_widget(Welcome(name='welcome'))
sm.add_widget(SelectionOption(name='selection'))


class Console(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('../Files/test.kv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Console().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `sm.current = "selection"` does not change the current `Screen` is because `sm` is a `ScreenManager`, but not the one that is in your GUI. I am seeing a lot of this lately. You are building your GUI twice. Once with the lines:

```
sm = windowManager()
sm.add_widget(Welcome(name='welcome'))
sm.add_widget(SelectionOption(name='selection'))
```

But the results of the above lines are not actually used. The GUI that you see when your code is run is built by the line:

```
return Builder.load_file('../Files/test.kv')
```

in your `build()` method.

So, you can safely eliminate those three unused lines of code.

Then, when you want to change the current `Screen`, you just need to get a reference to the `ScreenManager` that is used in your GUI. If you are doing this from within one of the `Screens`, you can get the reference from the `Screen`. So the line to change the current `Screen` from within a `Screen` can be:

```
self.manager.current = "selection"
```

Comment: Hi @John Anderson, thank you for your response. I would like to make the screen switch in the .py code than in the .kv file. Hence i was trying that approach to add the ScreenManager inside the .py file. Can you please tell me how i can make use of that in the current code above instead of .kv ? What are the changes to be made in .kv or .py file please ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The screen switch is done in the python code (`self.manager.current = "selection"`). Nothing in my answer changes any of your `kv`. Are you wanting to eliminate the `kv`?

Comment: I tried adding the below section in Welcome class under validate function.

```
def validatelogin(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()  # ScreenManager object

    if self.emailInput.text == "123" and self.passwordInput.text == "123":
        sm.current = "selection"
```

But i get this below error, as it is unable to identify the screen. however in my .kv file, i have specified name : “selection” in it for the SelectionOption screen

```
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "selection".
```

Comment: You are making the same mistake again. The code `sm = ScreenManager() ` is creating a new instance of `ScreenManager`, but it is not the one in your GUI. Try eliminating that line and replacing `sm` in that method with `self.manager`.

Comment: If i do that then i start getting this error. 
File "/Users/MobileApps/Python/AuthNavigation.py", line 18, in validatelogin
     self.manager.current = 'selection'
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'current' 

But i can see current defined as StringProperty in ScreenManager class as well. What further we should do here pls, James ?

Comment: You need to post this as a new question.